# A question about determinant of a specific matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $1\le a_1<a_2<...<a_d\le n$ and $1\le b_1<b_2<...<b_d\le n$, where each $a_i,b_j$ is an integer.

Let $M$ be an $d\times d$ matrix, s.t. the entry $M_{i,j}=0$ if $a_i\not= b_j$ and $M_{i,j}=1$ if $a_i=b_j$. Then is $det(M)=0$ if $a_i\not=b_i$ for some $i$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is *yes*, read further to see why.

Note that each row corresponds to one element of the sequence $a$, and each column corresponds to one element of the sequence $b$. Since all $a_i$ are distinct, each column contains at most one $1$, and the remaining entries are $0$. Similarly, since all $b_i$ are distinct, each row contains at most one $1$.

Suppose the determinant is nonzero. Then, none of the rows or columns can be entirely zero. Thus, for each $a_i$, there exists some $b_j$ such that $a_i = b_j$ and vice versa. This means that the sequences $a$ and $b$ are permutations of one another. But since they are both monotonically increasing, they must be the same.

However, if $a_i \neq b_i$ for some $i$, they cannot be the same sequence. A contradiction. The only way out is that the determinant is zero in this case.